# How to live update a Plotly figure created without Jupyter or Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I would like to update a Plotly figure that is already displayed in a browser window to create a live demo for a screencast.
I saw that there are many solutions for that using Jupyter or Dash, but I wanted to try
without.

As a MCVE example I tried to update the title of the plot in one second intervals.
I can see the dict changing, but the update does not arrive in the browser.
Any ideas how to solve that? Or is this not possible at all?

```
import plotly.express as px
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import random

mock_dict = {'x': [random.random() for _ in range(25)],
             'y': [random.random() for _ in range(25)],
             'z': [random.random() for _ in range(25)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mock_dict)   

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='y', z='z',
                    size_max=1,
                    color='z',
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Turbo,
                    title='Asd')

fig.show()

for _ in range(10):
    fig.layout.update(title=datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

    print(fig.layout)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: [This example here](https://holypython.com/how-to-create-plotly-animations-the-ultimate-guide/), which sadly doesn't have a data attached and so it is hard to judge if it is current best practices, uses `fig.write_html()` to write the HTML for the animation as it runs. As written, your code is meant to print some sort of fig layout that would have to be in active output connected to the python capable of rendering that. (I'm not sure your code even works in Jupyter? Hopefully your minimal MCVE does?) Maybe start with a non-animated plot & write HTML for that?

Comment: I know you seem opposed to doing this in Jupyter for some reason, but if you are mostly looking to make a screencast of it, you can use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) to make a dashboard like view that wouldn't have the Jupyter interface showing. It actually uses Jupyter, and so you can use code out there that works in Jupyter. It's not an animated plot, but if is Plotly in Voila, you can try by going [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder), pressing `launch binder` and selecting the second notebook listed, and then press Voila button along top.

Comment: if you are good with **flask** and a bit of javascript you can use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600501/refreshing-plotly-candlestick-plot-in-flask-app/71617009#71617009